# Unable to upgrade PEAR from 1.9.2 to 1.9.4

Tags: php, ubuntu, pear

I am on a Ubuntu 11.10 and trying to upgrade from 1.9.2 to 1.9.4, but it simply don't work. Here are the commands I am following in sequence

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-pear
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php-pear is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.0.0-14-generic-pae libaccess-bridge-java-jni libaccess-bridge-java
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
$ sudo pear channel-update pear.php.net
Updating channel "pear.php.net"
Channel "pear.php.net" is up to date
$ sudo pear upgrade-all
Nothing to upgrade-all
$ sudo pear install –alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit 
parsePackageName(): invalid package name "–alldeps" in "–alldeps"
invalid package name/package file "–alldeps"
Did not download optional dependencies: phpunit/PHP_Invoker, use --alldeps to download automatically
phpunit/PHPUnit requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.4), installed version is 1.9.2
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use package "phpunit/PHP_Invoker" (version >= 1.1.0)
phpunit/Text_Template requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.4), installed version is 1.9.2
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.4), installed version is 1.9.2
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage requires package "phpunit/Text_Template" (version >= 1.1.1)
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage can optionally use PHP extension "xdebug" (version >= 2.0.5)
phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.4), installed version is 1.9.2
phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject requires package "phpunit/Text_Template" (version >= 1.1.1)
phpunit/PHP_TokenStream requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.4), installed version is 1.9.2
No valid packages found
install failed
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `--alldeps` takes 2 - : `sudo pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit `

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two `-` required before the `alldeps` option! Try it with `--alldeps` and `--force`:

```
sudo pear install -–alldeps --force pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

Comment: The user needs instructions to upgrade the PEAR installer first, otherwise he will get messages like `Validation Error: This package.xml requires PEAR version 1.9.4 to parse properly, we are version 1.9.1`.

Comment: When there is a PEAR error about the wrong PEAR version do `sudo pear upgrade pear` first.